# PhaserJS: Detecting intersection

Tags: javascript, phaser

I'm making a card game to get my legs with phaser. I have an row of overlapping, face down cards. I want to detect when any card is covered by another card.

The deck is shuffled before being placed on the board, so the order is known `card[1]` thru `card[54]`. It goes `card.events.onInputDown.add(tap, this)` on each card during setup to detect interaction, and then calls `tap(this)`:

```
function tap(pointer){
    console.log(pointer.z);
    let zpos = pointer.z
    if (Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(pointer, *abovecard*)) {
        console.log("covered");
    } else {
        pointer.play("front"); // anim to show the card back
    }
}
```

*(`abovecard` is asterisked as a placeholder because I'm not sure what to put there)*

A simple boundary overlap check seems to be the model to use. But when I go `abovecard = card[zpos + 1]`, it doesn't see a card above it. Even when I do in the console `Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(card[37], card[38])`, which are visibly overlapping, it says `false`.

Primary question: What am I missing here?

2ndary question: Is there a better way, than what I've described, to detect if one sprite is overlapping another sprite (whether the other sprite is known or not)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it goes, as soon as I posted I figured it out.

`Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(pointer, card[zpos + 1]` needs an explicit rectangle. I thought I'd read that it automatically took the rectangle of the referred sprites, but it does not.

The solution is `Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(pointer.getBounds(), card[zpos + 1].getBounds()`